# Can't view image from webroot in CakePHP

Tags: css, image, cakephp

I am trying to display an image from the /webroot/img/ folder using the following CSS syntax: `.template-mainbg{background:#B8D9EA url('../img/bg_top.png') repeat-x left top;}`

The image never loads and if I try `http://site.com/img/bg_top.png` it gives me a Missing Img controller error.

This very wierd since the default Cake icon loads perfectly. Both from CSS and direct link.

What could be the problem?

Thank you!

**EDIT** I solved this problem. Unfortunately I spent 2 hours to figure out that Dreamweaver didn't sync the image with the remote server. Thank you anyway for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paths are relative to the CSS document, so it depends where the CSS file is being served from.

In the above example, `../img/bg_top.png` your CSS file would need to be in the site root I believe.

`The image never loads and if I try http://site.com/img/bg_top.png it gives me a Missing Img controller error.`

my understanding is that you can't access anything from "above" the webroot from a browser, hence the message.

Comment: Both my image and the cake image reside in the webroot/img/ folder, as I mentioned above. The difference is that my image doesn't load while cake's does. The images are referred to identically from CSS, `url('../img/bg_top.png')` and `url('../img/cake.icon.png')`